# Add Values into Nested Objects in PowerShell like you can in Python

Tags: python, json, powershell, hashtable, pscustomobject

I am looking use PowerShell to output some JSON that looks like this for use with a Python script:

> ```
>  {
> "run_date": "2020-08-27",
> "total_queries": 4,
> "number_results": 3,
> "number_warnings": 1,
> "number_errors": 5,
> "build_url": "https://some-url.com",
> "queries":{
>     "query_a":{
>         "database_a": "102 rows",
>         "database_b": "Error: See pipeline logs for details"
>     },
>     "query_b": "No results",
>     "query_c": {
>         "database_a": "Warning: Number of results exceeded maximum threshold - 6509 rows",
>         "database_c": "Error: See pipeline logs for details",
>         "database_d": "Error: See pipeline logs for details"
>     }
> } }
> ```

(Ignore the above closing bracket, it won't format properly on here for some reason).

I am using a foreach loop within PowerShell to run each of these queries sequentially depending on which databases they need to be ran on.

I know in Python I can create a template of the JSON like so:

> ```
> options = {
> 'run_date': os.environ['SYSTEM_PIPELINESTARTTIME'].split()[0],
> 'total_queries': 0,
> 'number_results': 0,
> 'number_warnings': 0,
> 'number_errors': 0,
> 'build_url': 'options = {
> 'run_date': os.environ['SYSTEM_PIPELINESTARTTIME'].split()[0],
> 'total_hunts': 0,
> 'number_results': 0,
> 'number_warnings': 0,
> 'number_errors': 0,
> 'build_url': 'https://some-url.com',
> 'queries': {} }
> ```

and then use something like:

> options['queries'][filename][database] = '{} rows'.format(len(data))

To add data into the Python dictionaries.

I've tried using nested PSCustomObjects but I end up with a conflict when different queries are being ran on the same database, so its trying to add a value to the PSCustomObject with the same Key. I would like to know if there is a nice 'native' way to do this in PowerShell like there is in Python.

Comment: I'm guessing you tried `ConvertTo-Json` from the powershell object?
`PS C:\> $json.queries.query_c.database_a = "600 rows"` and then `PS C:\>
PS C:\> $json | ConvertTo-Json`

Comment: Can you show the code that's failing due to key conflicts?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was just being a bit of an idiot and not remembering how to work with PowerShell objects.

Ended up first adding all the query names into the parent object like so:

```
foreach($name in $getqueries){
$notiObj.queries | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $name.BaseName -NotePropertyValue ([PSCustomObject]@{})}
```

Then adding in info about the queries themselves within the loop:

```
$notificationObj.queries.$queryName | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $database -NotePropertyValue "$($dataTable.Rows.Count) Rows"
```

Answer (score 0):

If the required end-result is a `Json` file, there is actually no need to work with complex (and rather fat) [`[PSCustomObject]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7) types. Instead you might just use a [`[HashTable]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7) (or an ordered dictionary by just prefixing the hash table, like: `[Ordered]@{...}`)

To convert *hash tables* from your Json file, use the `ConvertFrom-Json` [`-AsHashTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7#parameters) parameter (*introduced in PowerShell 6.0*).
To build a template (or just understand the PowerShell format), you might want to use this [`ConvertTo-Expression`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertTo-Expression/3.3.0) cmdlet:

```
$Json | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashTable | ConvertTo-Expression
```

```
@{
        'number_errors' = 5
        'number_warnings' = 1
        'queries' = @{
                'query_b' = 'No results'
                'query_a' = @{
                        'database_a' = '102 rows'
                        'database_b' = 'Error: See pipeline logs for details'
                }
                'query_c' = @{
                        'database_a' = 'Warning: Number of results exceeded maximum threshold - 6509 rows'
                        'database_d' = 'Error: See pipeline logs for details'
                        'database_c' = 'Error: See pipeline logs for details'
                }
        }
        'build_url' = 'https://some-url.com'
        'run_date' = '2020-08-27'
        'number_results' = 3
        'total_queries' = 4
}
```

Meaning you can assign this template to `$Options` as follows:

```
$Options = @{
        'number_errors' = 5
        'number_warnings' = 1
        'queries' = @{ ...
```

And easily change your properties in your nested objects, like:

```
$Options.Queries.query_c.database_d = 'Changed'
```

Or add a new property to a nested object:

```
$Options.Queries.query_a.database_c = 'Added'
```

Which result in:

```
$Options | ConvertTo-Json
```

```
{
  "run_date": "2020-08-27",
  "queries": {
    "query_a": {
      "database_c": "Added",
      "database_b": "Error: See pipeline logs for details",
      "database_a": "102 rows"
    },
    "query_b": "No results",
    "query_c": {
      "database_c": "Error: See pipeline logs for details",
      "database_d": "Changed",
      "database_a": "Warning: Number of results exceeded maximum threshold - 6509 rows"
    }
  },
  "number_results": 3,
  "build_url": "https://some-url.com",
  "total_queries": 4,
  "number_errors": 5,
  "number_warnings": 1
}
```